# no sound in headphone

Tags: headphones

Ubuntu 11.10, kernel 3.0.0.13.
Netbook medion AKOYA 1210.
There is no sounds comming out the headphones.
I have to go in the sound applet menu and switch off and on the sound card.
After that, sound come out of the headphones.

Is it a bug ?
Note I never encountered this issue since Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: You could try to update your kernel. If you open a console and type in `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. This will update other software as well.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

> aplay -l

The output should include the sound card number (ex. "card 1")

then run:

> alsamixer -c 1 (replace "1" with the number you got in previous command)

In alsamixer, turn the "speaker" volume up.

If you got sound, save the mixer state with:

> sudo alsactl store 1

Answer (score 1):

Under **Volume -> Sound Settings**,

Did you check Connector, which can be found at the bottom of the window on 12.04?

Sometimes, it does not change automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thought i'd supplement @erdemkeren answer with screenshots:

## Visit sound settings

Make sure to visit sound settings (click on the sound volume icon in the top right):
[image]

So sometimes you have to click on the orange box that i've shown below:
[image]

---

## Select your connect

Clicking on the connector will reveal a box with options. Most likely your best bet is the analog headphones. You may have other options as well. You may also have to switch your sound output device (Choose a device for sound output:

[image]